# Is there any way to print my polynomial exponents in superscript with C++?

Tags: c++

I am just wondering if there is any way to print a polynomial in a way like you write it on paper.

On computers, we usually write: 2x^2

But I want it to look like: 2x<sup>2</sup>

Comment: In plain text? You have limited characters and they're all [Unicode](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00B2), like x² or y⁹. In ASCII you simply can't do it.

Comment: print it to what? stdout is a character stream; it doesn't do superscripts.

Comment: @LScottJohnson excuse me? Superscripts are normal Unicode characters.

Comment: @L.Scott is right in that we can't tell you whether or not it's possible without knowing where you're trying to print. Are you trying to print in a unix shell? Maybe a qt window? Or is this part of a printer driver and you're trying to print onto a legal sheet?

Comment: @bipll what is the unicode string for x^0.2 ?

Comment: @sc0he001 I am a beginner.
I wanna print a polynomial in a normal way, I am using Console app in visual studio.

I can do it using ^,but I wanna print it like I am writing it on a paper, without using "^".

Comment: You will need to print in two lines.  First print the exponents, in their correct positions, then print the rest of the polynomial.  You will need to research your console to see if supports superscripts or different font sizes.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson polynomials by definition only contain integer exponents

Comment: @LScottJohnson you've got tough polynomials.

Comment: All the digits are available in superscript and subscript form if you can [print unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)

Comment: `printf("2x\u00b2\n");` will work on some systems https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/f8r48b

Comment: @Caleth I can't find the dot superscript to do the `x^0.2`

Comment: @bolov they de-implemented them, claiming that markup environments are the way to exist.

Comment: Can you output to HTML?  Or to TeX?  Or Postscript?

Comment: Tip: whatever solution, use a helper `print_super_expo(int expo)` to encapsulate the chosen approach - it may change.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this, but how you'll do it might depend on which system you're on.

I recently worked on a C++ project where I wanted to display subscripts and superscripts for readability's sake, along the lines of what you're proposing here. The challenge is that, on most systems, the `char` type does not let you store values corresponding to those superscripts. There are Unicode characters for those superscripts, and many C++ compilers will let you compile code containing those characters as long as you store them as strings. For example, I made this `std::unordered_map` to map from digits to superscripts:

```
    /* Map from numerals to their superscript equivalents. */
    const std::unordered_map<char, std::string> kSuperscripts = {
        { '0', "⁰" },
        { '1', "¹" },
        { '2', "²" },
        { '3', "³" },
        { '4', "⁴" },
        { '5', "⁵" },
        { '6', "⁶" },
        { '7', "⁷" },
        { '8', "⁸" },
        { '9', "⁹" },
    };
```

My compiler interprets these in UTF-8 format, so when I want to display them I can write things like

```
std::cout << kSuperscripts.at('0') << std::endl;
```

and it'll print `⁰` to the console.

Some systems use other encodings besides UTF-8 or some similar Unicode encoding. Not all C++ compilers can accept these characters in their source code, and some compilers might compile using a code page other than the one that the native system uses. But it might be worth trying out something like this to see whether it works on your machine.

Comment: to add the (sad) list of things that can go wrong: some terminals don't use or aren't setup to use Unicode and some fonts don't have these characters

Comment: Why not a simple array instead of a whole hashmap? your keys are basically numbers anyway

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili That's... a good idea. It's because I didn't think of it. :-) (Actually, there was a reason for it. I had written two routines, one that mapped from superscripts to normal digits and one going the other way, and I liked the symmetry and it wasn't performance-critical.)

Answer (score 2):

For consoles with fixed pitch fonts, try the old fashioned method:

```
std::cout << "  2\n";
std::cout << "2x\n";
```

The superscript is printed on the first line, then the terms on the second line.